# make two different string blocks with regex, php

Tags: php, regex

I have a long string and I want to extract two strings out of it.
i.e:
i want:

```
'Maria, C.'  *and*  'albS HmbF, Ctr Nat Haward Management, D-3020 Innsbruck, Austria'
```

from:

```
'[Maria, C.] albS HmbF, Ctr Nat Haward Management, D-3020 Innsbruck, Austria; [Marial, C.; Evans, K. F.; Eberhardt, E.; Loew, S.] Swiss Fed Inst Technol, Swiss Fed Inst Technol, Zurich, Switzerland; [Eberyardt, E.] Univ British Columbia, Vancouver, BC X6Z 1M3, Canada'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a regex that will do that https://regex101.com/r/Zqyyri/1

```
<?php

$regex = '/\[(?<name>.+)\](?<description>.+)\[/mU';

$string = '[Maria, C.] albS HmbF, Ctr Nat Haward Management, D-3020 Innsbruck, Austria; [Marial, C.; Evans, K. F.; Eberhardt, E.; Loew, S.] Swiss Fed Inst Technol, Swiss Fed Inst Technol, Zurich, Switzerland; [Eberyardt, E.] Univ British Columbia, Vancouver, BC X6Z 1M3, Canada';

preg_match($regex, $string, $matches);

echo $matches['name'] . $matches['description'];
```

Which outputs :

Maria, C. albS HmbF, Ctr Nat Haward Management, D-3020 Innsbruck, Austria;

Check it here https://3v4l.org/Ccrbm

Comment: I'd actually change it to: `/\[(?<name>.+?)\](?<description>[^;]+);?/gm` and `preg_match_all` to extract all occurrences

Comment: i noticed that semicolon afterwards. updated version https://3v4l.org/YO9pG